# How to make these radio buttons in the same <li> exclusive in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<li>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1">radio1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio2" value="2">radio2</label>
...
</li>
<li>
....
</li>
```

I tried this but failed:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    $.map($self.parents('li:first').find('input[type="radio"]'),function(n,i){
        if($(n) != $self)$(n).removeAttr('checked');
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "exclusive"?  Shouldn't you handle this by changing your markup to have all the inputs use the same `name` attribute value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `not` function to remove the current item from the selection:

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find("input:radio").not(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

*But if you just name then the same, they become exclusive automatically.*

```
<label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1">radio1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="2">radio2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need jQuery to make radio buttons exclusive, just give them the same name.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1">radio1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="2">radio2</label>
```

and you should be good.

Comment: I know this,but I can't this time